# Вывод строки с сообщением, если запрос не вернёт данных

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос в котором проверяется наличие того товара, который есть у поставщика, но при этом его нет на складе. При выполнении, запрос не возвращает никаких данных, т.к. на складе есть все товары, которые поставляют поставщики.

Как сделать так, чтобы в таком случае выводилось какое-либо сообщение, а не просто заголовок таблицы?

[image: Код запроса]
[image: Результат запроса]

Comment: Картезианское произведение выдаёт только пары, когда есть записи в обеих таблицах. Используйте стороннее (LEFT JOIN) связывание. Т.е., вероятно, нужно что-то типа `FROM товары INNER JOIN товары_у_поставщика LEFT JOIN (товары_у_поставщика MINUS товары_на_складе)`.

Comment: На будущее: код в вопросе следует приводить в виде текста. Иначе по нему не будет работать поиск, да и исправлять ваш код будет значительно  легче - можно скопировать код, а не набирать все с картинки.

Answer (score 3):

Можно просто соединить основной запрос со строкой по умолчанию, и если первый ничего не вернёт, то выведется как минимум одна строка с сообщением.

Попробуйте так:

```sql
with items as (
    select rownum id, 'item '||rownum  name  
    from xmlTable ('1 to 3')
),
supplier as (
    select rownum  id 
    from xmlTable ('1 to 3')
), 
stock as (
    select rownum id, 999 qnt from 
    xmlTable ('1 to 3') 
    where 1=1   
)
select coalesce (q.name, def.msg) name 
from (select 'all items in stock' msg from dual) def 
left join (
    select it.name
    from items it
    join supplier sp on sp.id = it.id  
    left join stock st on st.id = sp.id
    where st.id is null
) q on 1=1;
```

Результат:

```
NAME                                         
---------------------------------------------
all items in stock
```

Answer (score 0):

Только из спортивного интереса можно так накрутить)

```
    with s
      as (select '1' as id, 'nam1' as nam  from dual union all
          select '2' as id, 'nam2' as nam  from dual union all
          select '3' as id, 'nam3' as nam  from dual  
          )
       , t
      as (select '1' as val from dual /*union all
          select '2' as val from dual union all
          select '3' as val from dual */
          minus 
          select '1' as val from dual
          )         

    select s.nam
    from s
    where s.id in (select t.val from t)
    union all
    select 'Ok'
    from dual
    where case
            when (select count(1) from t) = 0
            then 1
            else 0
          end = 1
```

получаетя если нет разницы, то "зачем платить больше :)"

UNION ALL присоеденяет либо no rows selected либо 'Ok'